# Detecting the end of line

Tags: tex-core

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\mytextcolor}[2]{\textbf{1}\textcolor{#1}{#2}\textbf{2}}
\begin{document}
This is \mytextcolor{red}{red color} rest of the line
\end{document}
```

How can I define a similar command to `\textcolor`, say `\mytextcolor` so that

```
This is \mytextcolor{red}{red color} rest of the line
```

produces this (puts bold 1  and 2 between colored text):

[image]

If the colored text spans more than one lines like this:

```
This is a test as we can see so the next thing \mytextcolor{red}{red color so we can do this  here and there} rest of the line
```

Puts bold 1 and bold 2 like this:

[image]

and if the colored text even spans more lines, then the output would look like this:

[image]

**Note:** Using tikz or any other thing which uses `\special` is simply not wanted.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code.

Comment: You've tagged this as `tex-core` but you appear to be using LaTeX. Could you clarify? `tex-core` is for questions about things which don't use any format (e.g. LaTeX). Also, note that TikZ does not use `\special` - not typically, anyhow. Are you open to any other possible end results? I leave this to the TeX gurus, but I ask because I suspect that what you are asking is in the Extremely-Difficult-Any-Solution-Will-Break-All-Kinds-of-Stuff category, which is best avoided if possible.

Comment: You cannot avoid `\special` (or `\pdfliteral`) when you need colors.

Comment: @wipet: That is ok but using tikz or `\special` trick for detecting end of line is not ok.

Comment: @wipet I was guessing the aversion was tied to a preference for using pdfLaTeX rather than LaTeX but I could be wrong.

Comment: @user77791 Why not if you are using them anyhow?

Comment: @cfr: I added a minimal working example let me know if I need more than that. I used the `tex-core` tag because I think the solution needs some low-level TeX programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can show you the plain TeX solution. You can re-write this to your used macro package as a homework.

```
\input opmac
\localcolor

\newbox\semphAbox  \newbox\semphBbox
\setbox\semphAbox=\hbox{{\Black\bf1}}
\setbox\semphBbox=\hbox{{\Black\bf2}}%

\def\semph#1{\def\tmpb{#1}\replacestrings{ }{\specialspace}%
   {\Red\copy\semphAbox\tmpb\copy\semphBbox}%
}
\def\specialspace{%
   \discretionary{\copy\semphBbox}{\copy\semphAbox}{\kern\fontdimen2\font}%      
   \nobreak\hskip 0pt plus\fontdimen3\font minus\fontdimen4\font
}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\semph{Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
\semph{Pellentesque habitant} morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\bye
```

[image: semph]

Comment: Perfect. You gave me a solution to fix an TeX--XeT bug which existed for years. I have no idea how to thank you.

Comment: But this suppresses hyphenation, right? is there any other way to not effect hyphenation?

Comment: @user77791 Yes, the hyphenation is suppressed. I did a little correction of the code now (first `\discretionary`, second `\hskip`).  If you insert `\nobreak` immediately before `\discretionary` then hyphenation is allowed, but the lines with hyphenated words don't end by `{\bf2}`, they end only by hyphen.

Comment: @user77791 You mentioned that you need to fix a bug in TeX--XeT. IMHO, the right place where to solve such problem is source code of TeX--XeT, no `\discretionary` primitive.